# Silver Searcher: How can I only return results in folders matching a pattern?

Tags: command-line, terminal, grep, ag

My file structure is like this:

```
A
   G (want to ignore)
   H (want to ignore)
   X (contains files I want to search)
B
   G (want to ignore)
   H (want to ignore)
   X (contains files I want to search)
C (want to ignore)
X (contains files I want to search)
```

I want to only return results where X is *somewhere* the directory path.

It looks like I could use `ag foo --ignore={G,H}` but the list of folders to ignore would be very (almost prohibitively) long. I normally want to search in ALL of the folders so I could manually construct a global ignore file with everything and swap it in place when I want to ignore mostly everything.

I found that this syntax lets me search within `A` and `B`'s `X` folder so I'm close!

```
ag foo */X
```

So the question is essentially: How can I have an arbitrary number of forward slashes (0, 1, or more)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple `ag` command is not enough

I don't think this simply just via `ag` (The silver searcher) command only.  You need to somehow filter the input files from the whole directory tree, filtered based on `X` directory name.

I would do something along these lines:

```
ag 'search\sstring'  `tree -dfi | ag '\/X.*'`  | less
```

### What it does?

The command in:

```
`
```

is executed and the output is then searched via `ag`.

1. filter directories
   `tree -dfi` ... prints the whole path (dir and files) you want to search

- `-d` ... prints only directories
- `-f` ... prints full path prefix for each file
- `-i` ... skips spaces in the output (tries to be as processable as possible)

`ag '\/X.*'` ... searches for the directory `/X` within the path (followed by any character present 0 or many times) - use any regexp which will select the directory you want to search in.

2. search for a text within files

`ag 'search\sstring'` ... searches for the *'search string'* string within the filtered path

`less` is there for you to have searchable output (you can redirect any way you want)

Comment: I love this answer. Thank you for the effort you put into it! It makes sense and once I `sudo apt install tree`, I saw exactly what I wanted. Really great job making this as easy to understand as possible. Piping to less was unnecessary but I may still use that sometimes. Thanks again!

Comment: May require some massaging for working in a windows environment where `ag` works but `tree` is not as easy to use from what it appears. Glad I have the flexibility for both!

Comment: @veeTrain you are welcome. On WindowsI would use `MSYS2`. Other option would be cygwin or WLS2.